# Export from BigQuery to CSV based on client id

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a `BigQuery` table filled with product data for a series of clients. The data has been flattened using a query. I want to export the data for each client to a `Google Cloud Storage` bucket in csv format - so each client has its own individual csv.

There are just over 100 clients, each with a client_id and the table itself is 1GB in size. I've looked into querying the table using a cloud function, but this would cost over 100,000 GB of data. I've also looked at importing the clients to individual tables directly from the source, but I would need to run the flattening query on each - again incurring a high data cost.

Is there a way of doing this that will limit data usage?

Comment: >  I've looked into querying the table using a cloud function, but this would cost over 100,000 GB of data. 

Can you elaborate more of this here?

Comment: I was looking at looping over the client ids and running `select * from table where client_id = 123`, then saving the results of this query to a csv in `GCS`

Comment: do you have partitioning over clien_id col?

Comment: I don't at present

Comment: The best way to limit the querying of data is to create partitions. Details here - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#integer_range
----

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs#use_clustered_or_partitioned_tables

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into implementing this

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about Dataproc?

You could write simple PySpark script where you load data from BigQuery and Write into Bucket splitting by *client_id* , something like this:

```
"""
File takes 3 arguments:
    BIGQUERY-SOURCE-TABLE
        desc: table being source of data in BiqQuery
        format: project.dataset.table (str)
    
    BUCKET-DEST-FOLDER
        desc: path to bucket folder where CSV files will be stored
        format: gs://bucket/folder/ (str)
    
    SPLITER:
        desc: name of column on which spit will be done during data saving
        format: column-name (str)
"""

import sys
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

if len(sys.argv) != 4:
    raise Exception("""Usage: 
                    filename.py BIGQUERY-SOURCE-TABLE BUCKET-DEST-FOLDER SPLITER"""
                    )


def main():
    spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

    df = (
        spark.read
        .format("bigquery")
        .load(sys.argv[1])
        )

    (
        df
        .write
        .partitionBy(sys.argv[2])
        .format("csv")
        .option("header", True)
        .mode("overwrite").
        save(sys.argv[3])
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

You will need to:

1. Save this script in Google Bucket,
2. Create Dataproc cluster for a while,
3. Run command written below,
4. Delete Dataproc cluster.

Let's say you have architecture as follows:

**bigquery**: myproject:mydataset.mytable

**bucket**: gs://mybucket/

**dataproc cluster**: my-cluster

So you will need to run following command:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark gs://mybucket/script-from-above.py \
--cluster my-cluster \
--region [region-of-cluster] \
--jars gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest_2.12.jar \
-- \
myproject:mydataset.mytable gs://mybucket/destination/ client_id
```

This will save in **gs://mybucket/destination/** data split by **client_id** and you will have files named:

client_id=1

client_id=2

...

client_id=n

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Mr.Batra, you can create [partitions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables#create_an_integer-range_partitioned_table) on your table based on client_id to regulate cost and amount of data queried.

Implementing Cloud Function and looping over each client id without partitions will cost more since with each
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE client_id=xxx` the query will scan the full table.